# Action Bar in Android 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-2.3-gingerbread

I would like to use an Action Bar in my Android 2.2.3 application, so I have try to set up my project with the appcompat v7 support library. I've followed Google instructions so I have installed "v7 appcompat" as library project.

But after importing "v7 appcompat" and configuring the build path with Android 2.2.3, there are compilation errors like:

> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.

This compilation erros dissapear if I configure the build path with Android 4. But I would like to make it work with Android 2.2.3, as my application is for Android 2.2.3 (and above versions).

Thanks

Comment: Use Actionbarsherlock https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock it will support lower versions also..

Comment: Please post your sourcecode that is responsible for the error.

Comment: What do you mean with "configure the build path with Android 4" ? Are you using Android Studio/Gradle or Eclipse ADT ?

Comment: @mvnpavan, switching to ActionBarSherlock probably will not help, as ActionBarCompat is compatible with lower versions.

Comment: I am using Eclipse, and I mean that I configure my project to compile with Android 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must set build to android 4.0 or higher for using action bar compatibility. But don't worry, your application cant still run on 2.2.3.

Just set your minimum SDK version on yours.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to set build to android 4.0 or higher and I would test it. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting errors when I add 'appcompat' as a library project to my app project wich is built with Android 2.3.3. For example: styles_base.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.